# VB6 Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

Tags: vb6

I have been facing this issue for a couple days now.

It seems that on a client site I am recieving the automation error. The line of code in where im 90% sure it is coming from is below:

`Set oTemp = New cPMXMLParser`

However in other functions I seen

`Set m_oXml = CreateObject("PMXMLParser.cPMXMLParser")`

Which is essentialy the same except for the binding.

Please note both works locally but not on client site I was thinking maybe a dependancy is missing but seems not ... does anyone have any information on this?

Would

`Set m_oXml = CreateObject("PMXMLParser.cPMXMLParser")`

Be the best option?

Comment: The client machine probably has a different version of "PMXMLParser" than the machine you built on, and they aren't backward compatible. Read up on early- and late-binding to understand the difference between `Set x = New PMXMLParser` and `Set x = CreateObject("PMXMLParser.cPMXMLParser")`. This will help you decide the best solution. If "PMXMLParser" is written by you, read up on binary compatibility as well.

Comment: Late vs early binding is determined by the type of the variable (`oTemp`/`m_oXml`) and has nothing to do with object creation (`New` vs `CreateObject`) i.e. `Dim oTemp As Object : Set oTemp = New cPMXMLParser` will be late-bound while `Dim m_oXml As cPMXMLParser : Set m_oXml = CreateObject...` will make early-bound calls on `m_oXml`

Comment: @MarkJ yeah i think it could be because of Backwards compatibility... becauser CreateObject works fine. And I noticed the last pmxmlparser.dll on the client site is the previous version to what i built mine against.

Comment: That'll be the cause! And by the way @wqw is correct about early vs late binding.

Comment: @MarkJ Yeah it was that... the uuid of cPMXMLParser was different on the client site (because they had a different version) and thats why the early bind failed and the late bind failed. I decided to change the New to CreateObject because if cPMXMLParser changes we have to always ship that component.